# Infinite office building with main character trying to understand it

Tags: alternate-worlds, nonspherical-worlds

I was thinking about a story featuring a main character waking up in some kind of infinite alien "office" building. 
Infinite by means of number of rooms and all three directions, maybe with gangways between different "towers" that leap over an infinitley deep abyss.
This sounds weird, but I was thinking about what kind of singularity could cause something like that.
Any ideas? Let your creativity flow! :)

Excuse my English.

Comment: This is not a specific question, idea generation is off-topic

Comment: Hey there and welcome to WB.SE. It is always a joy to welcome a new user to the site, so it is quite a pain whenever we have to tell them that their question is not fit for the format of the site. We try to steer clear of questions that ask for things such as *any ideas?* or *let your ideas roam wild* and try to aim for more quantifiable questions and answers where we can help you solving a certain problem you face with your world. Please have another look at your question, if you need help you can always try the chatroom or the sandbox for proposed question on our meta site :)

Comment: Not the first time this happened to me. Thanks for the info, could you tell me how to make this question more "fit" for this site?

Comment: Look at [Cube (1997)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0123755/?ref_=nv_sr_2) for inspiration

Comment: "Infinite" is a really big word, Even the mind bogglingly huge structures that would be impossible to explore in the lifetime of the universe are puny compared to the infinite.So perhaps consider just a really big structure, such that the explorers see no end of it, cannot know if it is finite or not and are no more wiser. Having said that, I recommend reading *A Short Stay in Hell* by Steven L. Peck, where the main hero gets trapped in a finite, but still mind bogglingly huge structure.

Comment: @MarkusAppel Welcome to the site Markus.  Cool idea, but like the others mentioned it doesn't quite fit the format (which takes some time to get used to).  Check out the [help] for a little guidance on asking/answering questions.

Comment: I closed as "too broad", not "off topic". If you ask a question "how to I get to state X", it needs to be an X that can actually exist in reality for us to answer it. Infinite buildings do not exist, so any answer is going to be based in some sort of alternate science or magic system -- you need to supply that. Then we can work within those rules to figure out how it came about. But absent that, the answers are going to be all sorts of things like, "Well, assume Harry Potter..." or "Let's say Marvel Universe..." etc. It's too broad to answer. Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 suggestions:

**Just have your aliens use the entire planet as office space (intra-galactic admin is no joke).**

If your office structure covers the entire surface of the planet then, not only would it be so large as to be effectively infinite to any walking human, but it would also form a closed loop in any direction, so that one could travel indefinitely in any direction without ever finding an ending. (Towers and gangways could just be their way of building on the *unique* surface of this planet that is used for admin anyway because it is unsuitable for anything else)

As an added bonus, intelligent alien tech building technology that constantly reshapes rooms and furniture to best suit the needs of our office-workers at any given time, means that it would be impossible for your character to find himself in the same room twice, even if he makes several loops of the planet (which would take many decades anyway) as it will have been optimised out of existence.

OR:

**Have your character wake up in a computer simulation**

How they end up in here is irrelevant. (Are they fully immersed, TRON style, or is this more of a Matrix situation? Who knows?) The result, however, is an environment that a computer can easily expand in any direction in a generated "office" style, as required by the author, as far as, and as soon as, the character walks in that direction.

Procedural generation ensures that the environment always remains the same in a specific region, and sophisticated alien tech (made by HumanWare?) can easily handle it with its massive storage. (Although our Alien Admin might have to increase the storage space every now and then if the character gets too adventurous.)

Comment: I have just noticed the non-spherical worlds tag, but I'll leave the first part of this answer anyway as it might be useful.